# Why I receive tcp segment that shrink the window?

Tags: tcp

I was capturing packets with Wireshark on my laptop and found a packet send by the server shrink its receive window. It's a connection from my ubuntu18.04 to "connectivity-check.ubuntu.com".

I read rfc793 and TCPIP Illustrated volumn1, both say "is strongly discouraged to shrink the window".

Here is Wireshark's output. I disable HTTP dissection in Wireshark to prevent distraction.

```
   4198 0.026547255    2019-04-03 12:27:48.870761715 192.168.3.141         35.222.85.5           TCP      74     53846 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3960112411 TSecr=0 WS=128
   4199 0.281380222    2019-04-03 12:27:49.152141937 35.222.85.5           192.168.3.141         TCP      74     80 → 53846 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28160 Len=0 MSS=1412 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2281826280 TSecr=3960112411 WS=128
   4200 0.000092140    2019-04-03 12:27:49.152234077 192.168.3.141         35.222.85.5           TCP      66     53846 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=3960112693 TSecr=2281826280
   4201 0.000191823    2019-04-03 12:27:49.152425900 192.168.3.141         35.222.85.5           TCP      153    53846 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=87 TSval=3960112693 TSecr=2281826280
   4202 0.306769219    2019-04-03 12:27:49.459195119 35.222.85.5           192.168.3.141         TCP      66     80 → 53846 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=88 Win=26112 Len=0 TSval=2281826585 TSecr=3960112693
   4203 0.000076022    2019-04-03 12:27:49.459271141 35.222.85.5           192.168.3.141         TCP      214    80 → 53846 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=88 Win=26112 Len=148 TSval=2281826586 TSecr=3960112693
   4204 0.000028644    2019-04-03 12:27:49.459299785 192.168.3.141         35.222.85.5           TCP      66     53846 → 80 [ACK] Seq=88 Ack=149 Win=30336 Len=0 TSval=3960113000 TSecr=2281826586
   4205 0.000045328    2019-04-03 12:27:49.459345113 35.222.85.5           192.168.3.141         TCP      66     80 → 53846 [FIN, ACK] Seq=149 Ack=88 Win=26112 Len=0 TSval=2281826586 TSecr=3960112693
   4206 0.000183562    2019-04-03 12:27:49.459528675 192.168.3.141         35.222.85.5           TCP      66     53846 → 80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=88 Ack=150 Win=30336 Len=0 TSval=3960113000 TSecr=2281826586
   4207 0.245163856    2019-04-03 12:27:49.704692531 35.222.85.5           192.168.3.141         TCP      66     80 → 53846 [ACK] Seq=150 Ack=89 Win=26112 Len=0 TSval=2281826890 TSecr=3960113000
```

As the captured result shows, frame 4199 from server advertise a window sized 28160, but after receiving 87 bytes of data in 4201, the window shrinks to 26112 in 4202 which exactly equals to 2048(is that because server just swaps out a memory page?)

I want to know what can be the reasons for the server to shrink its TCP receive window? It's highly discouraged by RFC, I thought this kind of behavior wouldn't be implemented in TCPIP stack within an OS.

Comment: It might be the window scaling option defined in rfc1323. I have not read it in detail.

Comment: no, that's not what windows scaling means.

Comment: well, I would imagine that if window scaling is agreed upon during the 3WHS the window could change after completing the 3WHS. The first advertised window in the syn/ack may be unscaled, and then the second window in 4201 is scaled. That something is discouraged does not mean that it is not allowd. IW10 is standard, but many use much higher IW.

Comment: @FormerNcp No, that's not how window scaling works. Once scaling is agreed all windows are scaled. That's enough guesswork for one question.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behavior. When the Server receives data in its buffer and it cannot sent it immediately to the Application layer, it reduces the advertised window size to prevent dropping of received packets. **You are confusing this expected behavior with Shrinking of window problem, which occurs when we shift right edge of sender's buffer to left.**

You can refer this for more guidance on Shrinking of window problem: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPWindowManagementIssues.htm

Comment: Thanks for answering  :). But I am not confused with these two concepts. In the captured result I have shown, the window size is reduced by "2048", but the server only received "87" bytes of data. So the right edge did move to left.

Comment: Oh...I see.. I misinterpreted the question. Looks like you are correct the right edge moved left.